# TinyGP is giving me big spikes in the mean Avg Fitness functions on updating it to solve more complex symbolic regression examples

Tags: java, regression, fitnesse, gaussian-process

Hi every one I just started working with TinyGP to solve some simple symbolic regression problems to get a bitter understanding of genetic programming so I am basically working with sin(x) problem which is discussed in the books of Genetic programming
however i am finding that the Avg fitness function has big spikes like shown in figure dispute the Fact that the mean best fitness has no spikes and decreasing steadily as shown in figures
the second thing i want to make changes to the code to include non linear functions also[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzp1f.png]
[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/my7BO.png]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Right now your question is really hard to track as you've loaded code into images and don't explain exactly what you're expecting. I suggest you give [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a read and edit your question: You're more likely to get help that way.

Comment: I believe I replied to you on research gate. Short answer: some programs can pass selection that have a terrible fitness value. If you take the avg, they compromise it. Easy way out: take the median.

Comment: I saw your answer in research gate thanks very much it was really helpful